# Add row of text above a grid of items

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, panel

I'm building a grid via WPF, and it works great.  I need to add a row, or bar, or something to display above the grid, that will have several text items on it that will get populated by code.  I've been tooling around, and I can't seem to figure out how to put another panel above my existing (and working) grid.  This is my code:

```
<Window x:Class="GridWPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Board" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate_2">
            <Button Content="{Binding}" Height="25" Width="25" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate_1">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplate_2}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid Name="GridBoard" ShowGridLines="True">
        <ItemsControl x:Name="GridItems" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplate_1}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The GridItems gets populated by a jagged array, and displays fine.  I just need to put a few text objects above it, be it boxes, or just a horizontal panel that fits the width of the grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be the simplest option is to add a wrapper Grid and put your inner Grid in the second row. So, you will have the first row (row 0) to put anything you need there.

```
<Window x:Class="GridWPF.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Board" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate_2">
        <Button Content="{Binding}" Height="25" Width="25" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate_1">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplate_2}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid>
        <!-- WHATEVER YOU NEED -->
    </Grid>

    <Grid Name="GridBoard" ShowGridLines="True" Grid.Row="1">
        <ItemsControl x:Name="GridItems" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplate_1}"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you expect the output to look like, but you can nest your "GridBoard" `Grid` within another `Grid`. The new outer `Grid` defines two rows, whereby in the first row you can put your boxes or whatever you like. This could look like this for example:

```
<Window x:Class="GridWPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Board" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate_2">
            <Button Content="{Binding}" Height="25" Width="25" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate_1">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplate_2}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <TextBlock Text="Put something here ..." />
      </Grid>
      <Grid Grid.Row="1" Name="GridBoard" ShowGridLines="True">
          <ItemsControl x:Name="GridItems" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplate_1}"/>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Note that you could use any element for the content of the first row of your outer `Grid`. This depends on your actual needs. In this example I used another `Grid` which contains a single `TextBlock`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to achieve it.

## 1 - you can add a row and columns to your grid definition:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition width="*" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Then you can just assign 'headers' to each column, like so:

```
<TextBlock ... Grid.Column="0" />
<TextBlock ... Grid.Column="1" />
<TextBlock ... Grid.Column="2" />
```

And place your `ItemsControl` in the second row:

```
<ItemsControl ... Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
```

A half-assed way that may or may not work in your case. No way of knowing without taking a look at the `DataTemplate`.

## 2 - StackPanel at the top, with margin applied to the ItemsControl

You can use a similar half-solution - set the top margin of your `ItemsControl` to a fixed value, like so:

```
<ItemsControl ... Margin="2,48,2,2" />
```

And add a `StackPanel` to your grid:

```
<StackPanel Height="48" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <TextBlock Text="First Header" Width="300" />
    ...
</StackPanel>
```

I'm sure you get the idea.

## 3 - Use a GridView -RECOMMENDED-

This would require you to change your `ItemsControl` to a `ListView`, though.

[Here](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-with-gridview/) is a well-written tutorial on GridViews for WPF. Granted, it might not be what you're looking for, but again - without knowing what you're trying to present it's difficult to find best solution.